# Matrix exponent and representations of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, representation-theory, exponentiation

It is well known that $\exp(C^{-1}AC)=C^{-1}\exp(A)C$, where $C$ is an invertible matrix. Really,

$$\exp(A)=\sum{}\frac{A^k}{k!} \quad \text{and} \quad (C^{-1}AC)^k=C^{-1}A^kC,$$

so the first equality is obvious. The problem in the book on the representation theory is formulated as follows:

> Prove that $\exp(C^{-1}AC)=C^{-1}\exp(A)C$, avoiding explicit evaluations.

How to do it? Using some simple facts from linear algebra?

Comment: Already you have been given the facts that you need to prove it.

Comment: It is an explicit evaluation, isn't it?

Comment: You could say something along the lines of "conjugation by $C$ is an automorphism of the topological ring $\mathbb{M}_n\left(\mathbb R\right)$ (or whatever matrix ring you are working in), while $\exp$ is a formal power series and thus evaluation of $\exp$ commutes with automorphisms of topological rings". But this is really the same argument as you are doing, and I don't see any fundamentally different one. This kind of exercise usually doesn't speak well of the book.